Opening old project that uses Workflow C# (Project Type Guid 14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079) in VS 2019/2017
I have a Visual Studio solution, that has a project that requires Project Type Guid 14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079 (Workflow c#). I have installed the Windows Workflow Foundation individual component from Visual Studio Installer. But I am still unable to open the project in Visual Studio 2019 (Community) / 2017 (Professional)
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>


It seems that failing to load the project does not caused by GUID. Can you share a minimal reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without personal privacy through GitHub?
